# Why this program works else if parameters have passed through value?

Tags: c++, function, loops, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

In this program I allocate a squared matrix in the function inserimento but I passed the arguments by value and so it wouldn't worked but the output of printf is right.
Why?

// MAX is a costant that represents the both maximum of lines and rows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

using namespace std;

void insert(int **matrix,int &riga);
void print(int **matrix,int riga);


int main(){
    int *matrix[MAX];
    int riga;
    insert(matrix,riga);
    print(matrix,riga);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void insert(int **matrix,int &riga){
    int i,j;
    cout<<"Dimmi la riga"<<endl;
    cin>>riga;
    while(cin.get()!='\n');
    cout<<"c";
    *matrix=new int [riga];
    cout<<"c";
    for(i=0;i<riga;i++){
        matrix[i]=new int [riga];
    }

    for(i=0;i<riga;i++){
        for(j=0;j<riga;j++){
            cout<<"dimmi n"<<endl;
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void print(int *matrix[],int riga){
    int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<riga;i++){
            for(j=0;j<riga;j++){
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"\t";
            }   
            cout<<endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: You are passing a pointer-by-value.  You are not changing the pointer.  You are changing what the pointer points to.  What the pointer points to was not "pass by value" (it wasn't passed at all).  Note that C-style arrays readily _decay_ into pointers.

Comment: @Eljay ok thank you